# Local router interface cannot be reached from a certain device

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, router

I have a simple home network with a router (specifically a FRITZ!Box 7362 SL) and multiple devices connected to it via Wi-Fi. I would like to configure the router a bit so I tried to open up the login page on my laptop by entering the Default Gateway IP into a browser, yet regardless of the browser I use it gives me the standard "Unable to connect"/"Cannot reach this page" error. If I try to ping the Default Gateway IP Windows cmd gives me a General Failure.

Now here's the weird part: Not only is it possible to access the login page from any other device in the network but also when I boot up a VM on my Laptop I am able to access the page from there.

It must be some fault with my device therefore. Running a windows troubleshooter on the WLAN adapter gives the following result: Your computer appears to be correctly configured, but the device or resource (DNS server) is not responding.

Any help regarding this matter would be highly appreciated

**Edit: ipconfig /all output**

This is only the relevant adapter as I have a multitude of virtual adapters (for VPNs, Windscribe, etc)

```
Wireless LAN adapter WLAN:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : fritz.box
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek 8821AE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : B0-FC-36-55-7F-63
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fd00::89a0:2545:a12c:b8c6(Deprecated)
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : fd00::a88e:e1d7:e35e:a81e(Deprecated)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::89a0:2545:a12c:b8c6%21(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.65(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 15 April 2020 02:21:35
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 25 April 2020 02:21:35
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 263257142
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-25-22-EF-6D-B0-FC-36-55-7F-63
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fd00::3681:c4ff:fea6:b9a6
                                       192.168.178.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: Can you give us the IPConfig /all output ? and maybe confirm that the subnet//default gateway are the same on the other wireless devices

Comment: The default gateway is the same on all devices across the network

Comment: Maybe it’s one of the other adaptors which if your vm is bridged could explain the behaviour , can you try disabling the other adaptors? Or checking if they have the same sub nets Assigned?

Comment: I disabled all the other adapters but still get the same error. The packets are never leaving my device, I checked with wireshark... The VM Adapter has a different subnet, which might explain why that is working